# how to enable GPU option in user preferences

Tags: rendering

i was searching online tips to speed up the time of rendering, and i've found one screenshot which is like this [image]

but in my case there is no option of GPU in the compute device section, have a look at my screenshot 
[image]

am i missing any hardware ?

Comment: i am using linux and the link given says everything related to windows, so can anyone help me now please

Comment: and i have AMD hardware